# DefaultPreferences VS. SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

for months I have used defaultPreferences for multiple needs,but for current needs, I need multiple Preferences,thus, a second one must be added to the project. So I added a `Sharedpreferences` ,
All I did is exactly as I did for defaultPreferences. but what I get as result is "NULLY" for the `SharedPrefernces`! however I get what I want from the! `defaultPreferences`

my `Pref.xml` is:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:key="t2"
        android:summary="some text"
        android:title="some T"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:defaultValue="2"
    />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="mt2"
        android:summary="some text2"
        android:title="some T2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:defaultValue="2"
        android:entries="@array/mt2_setting"
        android:entryValues="@array/mt2_settingsvalues"/>
```

and I have called this SharedPreferences in anyway I knew.I ran the following part from OnCreate, from a inner method but no luck, just returning NULLY,

```
    SharedPreferences Prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String t2TEMP=Prefs.getString("t2", "NULLY");
    String mt2TEMP=Prefs.getString("mt2", "NULLY");
     Log.v("PREFERENCES VALUE:", "mt2 is: "+mt2TEMP+"*"+t2TEMP);
```

the context I use is `context=this.getBaseContext();` although I have tried `this` again with no luck.

if its any help I do apply default values before calling the preferences   `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefe, false);`
I really want to know what is the diference between `Default` and `Shared` Preferences that is stopping me.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure what you are looking for is

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

since preferences are saved there. You are pointing to a different SharedPreference file

Comment: I do have a DefaultSharefPrefrences, Im having problem with the second Preferences ( Shared )

Comment: preference screen preferences are saved in the default preferences

Comment: I think you got me wrong, I have 2 Prefes, the first one is accessed via DefaultPreferences, and it is ok. the second one cant be accessed via SharedPreferences.

Comment: Default preference and shared preference are the same thing

Comment: you are trying to access a shared preference value that is stored in default shared preferences but you point to a different shared preference file which you call `"pref"` and it will not exist in there

Comment: I have pref1.xml and pref2.xml. you say I can access both via getDefaultSharedPreferences. I gave it a try just now, no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62361/discussion-between-shervin-and-tyczj).

Comment: I cant access my pref2.xml values, however I can access my pref1.xml.
I used getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) for pref1.xml, and getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); for pref2.xml
so : this works ( from pref1) : SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String snd=sharedPrefs.getString("Def_Ringtone", "NULL");
but, this doesnt ( pref2 ) : SharedPreferences Prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String t2TEMP=Prefs.getString("t2", "NULLY");